# Inconsistent performance; PyMongo runs very slow compared to Mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a large MongoDB (3.4) collection on localhost with 10M+ documents. After I created an index by time field, I can query docs very quickly. Unfortunately, my PyMongo driver (3.2.2) running on Python 2.7.10 takes painfully long, in the 5 min window range, >50x longer.

This query in Robomongo runs in 0.1s:

```
var d1 = new Date('2016-08-06');
var d0 = new Date('2016-08-01');
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({'time': {$gte: d0, $lte: d1}}).limit(50000);
```

The Python version takes > 5min:

```
#Index created previously
#time_index = IndexModel([('time', DESCENDING)], name='time')

d0 = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1)
d1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 6)
coll = db['my_collection']
doc_filter = {'time': {
        '$gte': d0,
        '$lte': d1,
    }
}
doclist = [_document for _document in coll.find(doc_filter).limit(100)]
#doclist = [_document for _document in coll.find(doc_filter).hint('time').limit(100)]
```

The hint() method seems to have no effect either.
Any insight would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the list comprehension add a lot of time to the call? It seems unnecessary. Is it possible to switch the order of your method calls? ex: `coll.limit(100).find(doc_filter)` which might reduce time if it's in order of operations

Comment: I checked and the list comprehension isn't slow with a 100 docs. If I use: `cursor = coll.find(doc_filter)` and `print cursor.next()` that takes forever too. The limit is something I used artificially to make the point.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this SO answer?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8976768/1703772

Also: https://qnalist.com/questions/5279177/slow-performance-using-pymongo - tl;dr: Run `python -c 'import pymongo; print pymongo.has_c(); import bson; print 
bson.has_c()' ` and it should print `True` twice if you have c extensions installed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it just to be sure. Both return True. Also, I found at some point, the queries from Python started returning fast. But that was after Mongod started eating up > 12GB of memory and several queries. Can't duplicate the performance though after a restart.

Comment: It could be a bug in the software, but first, what is your OS and have you tried using python3 to do the same task?  Maybe a different python2.x version?

Comment: OS version is MacOS Sierra (10.12). I don't have the setup for Python 3. I will put in a workaround before changing python versions. Too many modules get affected.